# How to get all columns based on two columns using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like this:

```
sample  chr        start      end      ref   alt    gene    effect
AADA-01 chr1    12336579    12336579    C    T     VPS13D    Silent
AADA-02 chr1    20009838    20009838    -   CCA    TMCO4    Missense
AADA-03 chr1    76397825    76397825    GTCA T     ASB17    Missense
AADA-03 chr1    94548954    94548954    C    A     ABCA4    Missense
AADA-04 chr1    176762782   176762782   TCG  C     PAPPA2   Missense
AADA-04 chr1    183942764   183942764   -    T     COLGAL   Missense
AADA-05 chr1    186076063   186076063   A    TGC   HMCN1    Silent
AADA-05 chr1    186076063   186076063   A    T     HM1      Silent
```

I need all the lines where the 5th and 6th columns contain only one character.

And the result should look like:

```
sample  chr        start      end      ref   alt    gene    effect
AADA-01 chr1    12336579    12336579    C    T     VPS13D    Silent
AADA-03 chr1    94548954    94548954    C    A     ABCA4    Missense
AADA-05 chr1    186076063   186076063   A    T     HM1      Silent
```

I tried using this.

```
awk -F'\t' '$5' filename | awk -F'\t' '$6' filename | wc -l
```

I know this is wrong but can anyone correct my mistake please.

Comment: You will have to explain a bit more about how the expected output is derived from the given input.

Comment: Ya I know but I'm not aware about what I need to give. Could you please give me the right command.

Comment: I think you may want to take the values of 5th and 6th columns with this `awk` syntax: `awk 'OFS="\t" {print $5,$6}' dataframe_file`, but you haven't provided enough information about how you want to filter based on these fields.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio No that doesn't work.

Comment: We can't give you the right command if you don't tell us what you are trying to do. What is the relationship between your input and output? How do you get from the input to that output? You seem to just be printing 3 random lines. Please **[edit]** your question and explain your objective.

Comment: It is clear that you want to pick out a unique line for each sample, but I can't see what criteria you use to pick the one you do.

Comment: Very sorry. I edited now and I need all the columns based on "ref" and "alt" columns with single character.

Comment: And do you also want single nucleotide deletions? What if the ref is `T` and the alt is `-`, for example? Both `T` and `-` are single characters, should that line be printed?

Comment: yes..I made changes for that....do you think this is right? awk 'NR==1{print; next} $5 ~ /^[A-Z]$/ | awk -F'\t' '$6=="-"' filename

Comment: @user3351523: No you didn't. Please answer _terdon's_ last question

Comment: Actually for this question I need only Insertions

Comment: but @terdon Could you also tell me how to get the single nucleotide deletions.

Comment: Use Kusalananda's answer, but change the character range from `[ACTG]` to all allowed characters: `[ACTG-]` or, depending on what you are doing, `[ACTGUN-]`. So, something like `awk '$5 ~ /^[ACGT-]$/ && $6 ~ /^[ACGT-]$/ || NR == 1' data.in`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{print; next}
     $5 ~ /^[A-Z]$/ && $6 ~ /^[A-Z]$/' input.txt
```

**Explanation**

```
NR==1{print; next}
```

This prints the first line (header) unconditionally and goes to the next line.

```
$5 ~ /^[A-Z]$/ && $6 ~ /^[A-Z]$/
```

This is a conditionnal expression: if the 5th AND the 6th arguments both match a single upper case letter, then print the line (the print command is implicit in this case being the default instruction for any condition).

`$5` and `$6` stand for the 5th and 6th column for each line.

`&&` is the logical operator AND.

`~` is the regexp matching operator. It returns true if the argument on the left-hand side matches the regexp on the right-hand side.

`/^[A-Z]$/` is a regular expression (regexp). The character "/" is a delimiter for the regexp, "^" indicates the beginning of a line (or the string), "$" the end, and "[A-Z]" means all upper case letters from A to Z.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '$5 ~ /^[ACGT]$/ && $6 ~ /^[ACGT]$/ || NR == 1' data.in
```

This will, for the given data, generate

```
sample  chr        start      end      ref   alt    gene    effect
AADA-01 chr1    12336579    12336579    C    T     VPS13D    Silent
AADA-03 chr1    94548954    94548954    C    A     ABCA4    Missense
AADA-05 chr1    186076063   186076063   A    T     HM1      Silent
```

The `awk` script tests columns 5 and 6 to see whether they are any of the single character `A`, `C`, `G` or `T`, or if the current line is the first line of the file.  If so, it will print that line.

The test `$5 ~ /^[ACGT]$/` means "see if column five matches the regular expression `^[ACGT]$`".  The regular expression will match anything that contains a single character in the given set (`[ACGT]`).

`^` and `$` are "anchors", they will only match in the very start and very end (respectively) of the given data (column five and column six).

`&&` and `||` are the logical AND and OR operators.

`NR` is the ordinal number of the current input line.  If `NR == 1` then the current line is the header line in the file. Since the header line doesn't fulfill the criteria to be outputted (`ref` and `alt` are not single letters and so wouldn't match the regular expression), this separate test has to be made to be sure to get it in the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print if $. == 1 or 2 == grep /^[A-Z]$/, @F[4,5]' data.in
```